# Export my CSS vars with my module using rollup?

Tags: sass, rollupjs

I have a little module that I am sharing across a few projects. It is successfully exporting components, but now I'd like to get my global style vars, like `$contoso-primary: #ff0000` to be exported as well so we can start sharing CSS vars in my consuming app, like `background-color: $contoso-primary`. I'm using the rollup.js, is this possible with this library or with its plugins? If so, what plugin am I looking for? I've tried postcss already but doesn't appear to work unless I'm missing something.

```
export default {
  input: 'src/index.js',
  output: [
    {
      file: pkg.main,
      format: 'cjs',
      sourcemap: true
    },
    {
      file: pkg.module,
      format: 'es',
      sourcemap: true
    }
  ],
  plugins: [
    external(),
    postcss({
      extract: true
    }),
    url(),
    svgr(),
    babel({
      exclude: 'node_modules/**'
    }),
    resolve(),
    commonjs()
  ],
  onwarn(warning, warn) {
    if (
      warning.code === 'CIRCULAR_DEPENDENCY'
      && warning.importer.indexOf('node_modules/semantic-ui-react') > -1
    ) return;
    warn(warning);
  }
};
```

my `scss` file that has my vars looks something like:

```
$primary: #177757,
$secondary: #D50000
```

and in the consuming project I'd like to refer to these in my `scss` files like:

```
.button {
  background: $primary
}
```

I can't get an `.css` file into my dist folder, and the documenation on rollup-plugin-postcss is a little light.

Answer (score 1):

[postcss-simple-var](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-simple-vars) this plugin will able to share sass like variables.

```
plugins:  [
      postcss({
        plugins: [
          simplevars()
        ],
      extensions: [ '.css' ],
    }),
    ...
  ]
```

for more information read [this](https://lengstorf.com/learn-rollup-css/) article.

Comment: doesn't work, using code the same way you are. I added more context above I think may play a part. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make this work by duplicating the variable declarations in both the `postcss.config.js` and `rollup.config.js`

Rollup config:

```
import postcss from "rollup-plugin-postcss";
import postcssSimpleVars from "postcss-simple-vars";
const variables = require("./pathTo/variableConfig.js");
...
const config = {
...
plugins: [
  postcss({
    postcssSimpleVars({
      variables: function () {
         return variables;
      }
    }),
  })
]
```

postCSS config:

```
const variables = require("./variableConfig.js");

plugins: [
 ...
  require("postcss-simple-vars")({
    variables: variables
  })
]
```

variableConfig.js:

```
const baseDir = "../src/utils/constants";
const { COLORS } = require(`${baseDir}/colors`);
const { MQ } = require(`${baseDir}/mediaQueries`);
const { BREAKPOINTS } = require(`${baseDir}/breakpoints`);

const cssVars = Object.assign(COLORS, MQ, BREAKPOINTS);

module.exports = cssVars;
```